# How to get value of kendo combobox in the change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, kendo-ui

I have 2 questions on kendo combobox change event.

1. On change event I want to get the selected value of that combobox.
2. I want to get the reference to the parent element or an element itself.

How to do that? Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/fYXyp/1/)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use `this.value();`

```
alert("value: " + this.value());
```

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/events.html

**Edit:**

For question #2 - use `this.element` to get the element itself, and `this.element.parent()` to get element's parent.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I tried this.val() and this.value but don't know why didn't I tried this.value()

Comment: Any idea how to do the 2nd one? I have added that in the question.

Comment: @MotaBOS I have updated the answer, although this should really be in another SO question.